# India and China's trade future with Iran

Tags: donald-trump, india, china, iran, geopolitics

Please give specific answers rather than trivial ones.

- As Donald Trump has warned to impose sanctions on all countries
  trading petroleum resources with Iran, what is the  *present* trade
  scenario of *Iran* with other countries, especially *India* and
  *China*?

  - Are both countries lately trading in a currency other than dollars or
    have they stopped trading?
  - If they have stopped trading or reduced trade volume then how are these
    countries fulfilling their energy requirements?

Answer (score -1):

First, Iran-India mulled over [gold](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/industry/energy/oil-gas/india-iran-mull-over-gold-for-oil-for-now/articleshow/7238760.cms?from=mdr). Then, India paid [in EURO](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-india-iran-oil-payments/india-pays-part-of-iran-oil-dues-ahead-of-modi-visit-idUSKCN0YC09O#:%7E:text=NEW%20DELHI%20(Reuters)%20%2D%20Indian,the%20payment%20said%20on%20Saturday.). Now they trade-in [Indian currency](https://m.economictimes.com/industry/energy/oil-gas/india-set-to-pay-for-iranian-oil-using-rupees-from-november-sources/articleshow/65887179.cms).

And, China is trading using the Chinese currency.

So, I don't think anything changes.

Comment: The first link is 9 years old, the second link is 4 years old, and the third link is from almost two years ago and even states that it predates the imposition of US sanctions.

Comment: @JustMe, and, this question is also a year old.

Comment: That's not a reason to post links that simply can not answer the question as they predate the imposition of sanctions.